# R apply with dynamic argument

Tags: r, loops, dynamic, arguments, apply

I am just wondering if it is possible to use apply function so that before using the next i index, one of the arguments is refreshed. Let me introduce an example:

I have a simple 10-element vector:

```
a<-c(1,rep(NA,9))
```

And define a function that replaces i-th element of a with sum of 2 and the previous one:

```
fun<-function(i,vec){
  vec[i]<-2+cumsum(vec)[i-1]
  a<<-vec
}
```

Now I would like to use sapply, f.e.

```
sapply(2:10,fun,vec=a)
```

so that in result I get vector `1,3,...19`.

I know that it is pretty easy to accomplish in a for-loop but I would try apply to see if it's considerably faster solution.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Bart

Comment: The best solution is always vectorization: `1 + (0:9) * 2`

Comment: functions with sideeffects are dangerous `<<-`

Comment: Sure vectorization is best, but the real problem is more complex. What I add in following steps depends on previous results (previously populated values of a)- here the example is as simple as it could be just to present the idea

Comment: You are unclear with the constitution of your vector `a`. E.g. which of it's attributes are variable (first value, any value, length). For your example @Roland has the solution shown.

Comment: Please provide a specific and representative example. `*apply` loops are still loops and not faster than a well-written `for` loop (with the slight exception of `vapply`). However, if your problem is truly recursive, it's often easiest and best to turn to a compiled language (i.e., Rcpp).

Answer (score 0):

The below code is a possible solution to your question if I understood it correctly.  As @jogo mentioned in the comments on your question the deep assign function `<<-` causes side effects which can be dangerous.  To get your code working I applied over the indices of `a` as opposed to the elements.

Loops get a bad rap in R but they're not always a bad thing.  In this case the `sapply` I came up with to fit your solution is actually slower than a competing loop solution (as measured with `microbenchmark`), and the loop has the advantage of not relying on side effects.

#### sapply solution

```
a <- c(1,rep(NA,9))
fun<-function(i,vec){
  a[i] <<- 2+cumsum(vec)[i-1]
}

sapply(seq_along(a)[-1], function(i) fun(i,a))
```

#### loop vs sapply

```
loopSoln  <- function() {
  a <- c(1,rep(NA,9))
  for(i in seq_along(a)[-1]) {
    a[i] <- 2+cumsum(a)[i-1]
  }
  return(a)
}


fun<-function(i,vec){
    a[i] <<- 2+cumsum(vec)[i-1]
  }
applySoln <- function() {
  a <- c(1,rep(NA,9))
  sapply(seq_along(a)[-1], function(i) fun(i,a))
  return(a)
}

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(loopSoln(), applySoln())

Unit: microseconds
       expr    min      lq     mean  median      uq     max neval
 loopSoln() 28.915 30.6960 34.36206 32.5115 33.9085  99.525   100
applySoln() 77.664 80.9815 88.13986 83.1465 85.3815 207.569   100
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll definitely try out your solution and get back with the info if it could be really save me some computing time.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware, you cannot do this kind of calculation using the *apply family.

EDIT: Ops, just saw the answer. Let me rephrase, cannot be done without global assigment '<<-'

The reason is that *apply requires all input values beforehand. Any recursive function like yours you not work without transformation.

I see one way of adding an *apply function and make it faster, but it requires some math by your part: You could try to solve the recursion on your equation.

Using the example given, we have that.

```
vec[i] = 2 + cumsum(vec[i-1])
```

Mathematically that is equivalent to:

```
vec[i]= 2 +2 +cumsum(vec[i-2])+cumsum(vec[i-2])
```

Following this reasoning we get:

```
vec[i]=2*i +vec[1]*i
```

Which can be used in a lapply:

```
non.rec <- function(x,initial) {2*x+initial*x}
lapply(2:10,non.rec,initial=1)
```

This might be very complex depending on the function you are dealing with. Therefore there is a trade-off between the time you want to invest simplifying this equation and speed the computer will gain.

Comment: Thanks for commenting! Unfortunately I am dealing with SDEs without an analytical solution but can agree that when applied to simple problems your solution is pretty neat.